# How to append new rows of data to another excel sheet/table?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a table of source data like this:

| ID | Color |
| --- | --- |
| B12 | Blue |
| C14 | Yellow |
| J14 | Jaune |

And I have a named table (in another sheet) where I'd like to send data that looks like this (same structure as source data):

| ID | Color |
| --- | --- |

I want the vba code to do the following:

1. check if the target table contains the case IDs in the source data
2. if the case ID does not exist, append rows from source data to the target table
3. if the case ID does exist, update records in the target table according to the values in the source data, if the values are different.

It is important that the code never removes rows from the target table. ie if the source data is updated and a row is removed, the target table should still contain any removed rows. so rows can only be added to the target table, or updated if there are matching case IDs in both tables.

EDIT:

here is an answer from [another stack question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44200615/vba-to-copy-excel-worksheet-append-new-rows-from-specific-columns). though I have no clue how to adapt this code to fit my needs:

```
' COPY, PASTE AND APPEND   
Sub Append()

Dim manager As String, lastrow As Long, i As Integer, k as integer, j as integer
Dim find As Range, bill As String

bill = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A:A").Value
Do While Not bill = ""
Set find = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A:A").find(what:=bill, lookat:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)

If find Is Nothing Then

lastrow = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row

For i = 2 To lastrow
    If Cells(i, 2) = "JOHN" Then
    Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, 6)).copy
    Sheets("Sheet13").Range("A300").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial
    End If
Next i

For j = 2 To lastrow
    If Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(j, 2) = "CHARLIE" Then
    Sheets("Sheet1").Range(Cells(j, 1), Cells(j, 6)).copy
    Sheets("Sheet11").Range("A300").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial
    End If
Next j

For k = 2 To lastrow
    If Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(k, 2) = "GEORGE" Then
    Sheets("Sheet1").Range(Cells(k, 1), Cells(k, 6)).copy
    Sheets("Sheet12").Range("A300").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial
    End If
Next k

Else

Sheets("Sheet1").Select

End If
Loop

End Sub
```

The above script first looks for manager names in the source data and then copies the data to sheets according to the manager names (which I don't need to do, since all my source data should be pasted to the same sheet). also, I don't think the above script is updating any records, which I need to do in my target table.

Comment: What code have you tried? Please post it even if it doesn't work.

Comment: I will post one code from another stack question which helped another user -- I just have no clue what I need to modify to fit my needs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Dictionary` object is a good option for you.

```
Sub demo()
    Dim srcSht As Worksheet, desSht As Worksheet
    Dim arrDes, arrSrc, objDic
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    ' Update sheet name as needed
    Set srcSht = Sheets("Sheet1") ' source sheet
    Set desSht = Sheets("Sheet2") ' dest. sheet
    ' Load data into array
    arrSrc = srcSht.[a1].CurrentRegion.Value
    arrDes = desSht.[a1].CurrentRegion.Value
    Set objDic = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    ' Add data to dict object from dest table
    For i = 1 To UBound(arrDes)
        objDic(arrDes(i, 1)) = arrDes(i, 2)
    Next
    ' Update / insert data into dict object
    For i = 1 To UBound(arrSrc)
        objDic(arrSrc(i, 1)) = arrSrc(i, 2)
    Next
    ' write data to dest table
    desSht.Range("A1").Resize(objDic.Count, 1) = Application.Transpose(objDic.keys)
    desSht.Range("B1").Resize(objDic.Count, 1) = Application.Transpose(objDic.items)
    Set objDic = Nothing
End Sub
```

---

**Update**

> Question: there are about ~20 columns and it is possible that the number of columns might change, so I need to know how to modify the script to pick up additional columns

> Note: The code supports multiple key columns, but they must be the first N contiguous columns. You can adjust the number of key columns by modifying the constant KEY_COL_CNT as necessary.

```vb
Option Explicit
Sub demo()
    Dim srcSht As Worksheet, desSht As Worksheet
    Dim arrDes, arrSrc, arrRes()
    Dim objDic, arrItem, sKey As String
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, ColCnt As Long
    Const KEY_COL_CNT As Integer = 2 ' # of key columns
    ' Update sheet name as needed
    Set srcSht = Sheets("Sheet1") ' source sheet
    Set desSht = Sheets("Sheet2") ' dest. sheet
    ' Load data into array
    arrSrc = srcSht.[a1].CurrentRegion.Value
    arrDes = desSht.[a1].CurrentRegion.Value
    ColCnt = UBound(arrDes, 2)
    Set objDic = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    ' Add data to dict object from dest table
    For i = 1 To UBound(arrDes)
        sKey = ""
        For j = 1 To KEY_COL_CNT
            sKey = sKey & "|" & arrDes(i, j)
        Next
        objDic(sKey) = Application.Index(arrDes, i)
    Next
    ' Update / insert data from src table
    For i = 1 To UBound(arrSrc)
        sKey = ""
        For j = 1 To KEY_COL_CNT
            sKey = sKey & "|" & arrSrc(i, j)
        Next
        objDic(sKey) = Application.Index(arrSrc, i)
    Next
    ReDim arrRes(objDic.Count - 1, 1 To ColCnt)
    ' Get items from dict object
    arrItem = objDic.items
    ' Transform to 2D array
    For i = LBound(arrItem) To UBound(arrItem)
        For j = 1 To ColCnt
            arrRes(i, j) = arrItem(i)(j)
        Next j
    Next i
    ' write data to dest table
    desSht.Range("A1").Resize(objDic.Count, ColCnt) = arrRes
    Set objDic = Nothing
End Sub
```

[image]

---

**Update**

> Question: but is it possible to paste the data into an actual table?

> Note: The only difference is expanding the table before updating cells.

```
    ReDim arrRes(objDic.Count - 1, 1 To ColCnt)
    ' Get items from dict object
    arrItem = objDic.items
    ' Transform to 2D array
    For i = LBound(arrItem) To UBound(arrItem) - 1
        For j = 1 To ColCnt
            arrRes(i, j) = arrItem(i + 1)(j)
        Next j
    Next i
    ' write data to dest table
    Dim rTab As Range
    Set rTab = desSht.Range("A1").Resize(objDic.Count, ColCnt)
    desSht.ListObjects(1).Resize rTab
    Set rTab = desSht.Range("A2").Resize(objDic.Count - 1, ColCnt)
    rTab.Value = arrRes
```

Comment: ahh this seems to be exactly what I need! question -- just tried this and the code is only picking up data from the first two columns of the source data. what do I need to modify to carry over other columns of data?

Comment: Your sample data only have two columns in OP. How many columns do you have? Is the number of columns fixed?

Comment: In my actual data, there are about ~20 columns and it is possible that the number of columns might change, so I need to know how to modify the script to pick up additional columns

Comment: Is the first column the key to identify the data row?

Comment: yes, I can use power query to modify the source table layout to put the key column wherever (such as the first column position)

Comment: I have updated the code.

Comment: updated code works like a charm. I don't know if this is too much to ask -- but is it possible to paste the data into an actual table? since I am building a power query off of the destination worksheet data, power query looks for a named table. but when we update the destination data, the named table is removed

Comment: Is it the final output? It would be better ask for the final expected result on OP.

Comment: yes, the named table is the final output. sorry, I didn't even realize which details would completely alter the solution, I'll know to be much more detailed in my future questions

Comment: Pls check the updated code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255475/discussion-between-brenda-thompson-and-taller-excelhome).